# ExpressJS determine IP and interpret it

Tags: node.js, express, io.js

I'm trying to find out in my ExpressJS app if the request comes from the localhost by using `req.ip`, however, it seems like the the value is different for different OSs. On my Ubuntu machine `req.ip` results in `::ffff:127.0.0.1`, on a Mac though, it results in `::1` when I call the website via localhost. Is there anyway how to determine whether the request comes from localhost on all OSs?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip.

Also, I found gist: https://gist.github.com/qiao/1626318